# selenium framework-popup-xpath repository issue

Tags: selenium, frameworks

I follow selenium framework .In which while working on popup, I am unable to use xpath repository class  on popup window as it requires a Iwebelement instead on xpath.

Please help me with it.

Comment: Hi @siva, how can someone will help with provided information? Share more information about your question like - what have you tried so far? Try to add screenshots and html source if possible and website link also if its sharable otherwise with the provided info, it is very difficult to help

Comment: Show your [mcve] as discussed in [ask]. Remember that no one is going to design and write this code for you.